# How can I access the internal LDAP-directory of Websphere Portal 6.1?

Tags: ldap, websphere-portal

I'd like to access the internal user directory of a Websphere Portal 6.1 server from outside (say, from a LDAP-Browser on the same machine). Is there a LDAP interface that is usable for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebSphere Portal by default uses a database user registry until you actually configure security.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out the the file is stored in the following path \profiles\\config\cells\\fileRegistry.xml

Answer (score 0):

A very good LDAP Browser workfing on top of java on both Linux and Windows is [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/) an Eclipse based LDAP browser and directory client.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a LDAP interface to see the interanl user registry of WebSPhere. As Far as I know this is a XML file store. Where this XML files is stired in the directory structure of WebSphere is something I don't know :-)